# error in acts_as_taggable_on_steroids - tags_counts method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The tag_count method gives the same value for all the records
In my GroupsController I have:

```
    @group_blog_tags=@group.blog.blog_posts.tag_counts
```

where

```
     class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :blog, :as => :owner, :dependent => :destroy


      class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
          has_many :blog_posts, :order => "blog_posts.created_at desc", :dependent => 
            :destroy
```

But it is always fetching the first record in the tags table regardless of which group I choose.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@group=Group.find(45)  => #<Group id: 45, name: "Royal P&O Princess", description:                        
        "Royal P&O Princess the next edit", created_at: "2013-03-04 06:04:57", 
        primary_photo_id: 807, updated_at: "2013-03-14 07:33:37", tags: "Caribbean, 
        Nile, Mediterranean", group_memberships_count: 2, group_type: 1, 
        last_updated_by: 1, content_updated_at: "2013-03-04 11:05:08", activity_points: 
        0, activity_status: 0, no_memberships_on: nil, owner_id: 28, sponsor_account_id: 
        65, views: 241, company_id: 0, active: 1, de_flag:0  

@group.blog.blog_posts => [#<BlogPost id: 12, created_at: "2013-03-20 05:08:56", 
       updated_at: "2013-03-20 05:08:56", blog_id: 74, creator_id: 1, title: "South 
       African Sojourn", text: "<p>\r\n\tSouth African Sojourn</p>\r\n", comments_count: 
       0, created_at_year_month: 201303, cached_tag_list: "Africa, Veldt", rating_count: 
       0, rating_total: 0, rating_avg: #<BigDecimal:b2de1978,'0.0',4(8)>, views: 1, 
       source: nil, link: nil, guid: nil, tagline: nil, creator_type: "Profile", 
       num_positive_votes: 0, num_negative_votes: 0, net_helpful: 0, best_image: nil, 
      active: 1>, #<BlogPost id: 11, created_at: "2013-03-20 03:46:07", updated_at: 
      "2013-03-20 03:46:07", blog_id: 74, creator_id: 1, title: "African safari", text: 
       "<p>\r\n\tAfrican safari&nbsp;Africa, Safari&nbsp;Afric...", comments_count: 0, 
       created_at_year_month: 201303, cached_tag_list: "Africa, Safari, Veldt", 
       rating_count: 0, rating_total: 0, rating_avg: #<BigDecimal:b2de1518,'0.0',4(8)>, 
       views: 1, source: nil, link: nil, guid: nil, tagline: nil, creator_type: 
       "Profile", num_positive_votes: 0, num_negative_votes: 0, net_helpful: 0, 
       best_image: nil, active: 1>, #<BlogPost id: 2, created_at: "2013-03-04 06:34:53", 
      updated_at: "2013-03-04 06:34:53", blog_id: 74, creator_id: 28, title: "New blog 
       post", text: "<p>\r\n\tNew blog post</p>\r\n", comments_count: 4, 
      created_at_year_month: 201303, cached_tag_list: "New blog post", rating_count: 0, 
       rating_total: 0, rating_avg: #<BigDecimal:b2de1414,'0.0',4(8)>, views: 7, source: 
       nil, link: nil, guid: nil, tagline: nil, creator_type: "Profile", 
       num_positive_votes: 1, num_negative_votes: 0, net_helpful: 1, best_image: nil, 
       active: 1>]  

       @group.blog.blog_posts.tag_counts          => [#<Tag id: 1, name: "acticity 
     stream message">]     


       Trying another group:
       Group.find(40).blog.blog_posts.tag_counts  => [#<Tag id: 1, name: "acticity 
       stream message">]
```

Its always fetching the same records as result!

Answer (score 0):

I think a group "belongs_to" a blog, and not "has_one".

*Edit*

You have to specify the relation between group and blog. It can be this cases:

- A group has_one blog, a blog belongs_to a group
- A group has_many blogs, a blog belongs_to a group
- A group belongs_to a blog, a blog has_one group
- A group belongs_to a blog, a blog has_many groups
- A group has_one_and_belongs_to_many blogs, a blog has_one_and_belongs_to_many groups

A `x belongs_to y` implies you have a `y_id` in your `x` table.

A `x has_one y` or `x has_many y` specify the number of `y` for each `x`.

A `x has_and_belongs_to_many y` implies `x` has many `y` and `y` has_many `x`.

Comment: The group is the owner (i.e. a group owns a blog), how can I change it to belongs to?

Comment: I made the change as you suggested i.e. added belongs_to :group inside the Blog model, still no luck :( For ex: when I do group.blog.blog_posts it is correctly listing all the blog_posts in this group but when I try to get group.blog.blog_posts.tag_counts, it is always showing the same result (for all groups)...Please help!

Comment: @user1865578 Can you show the database query displayed in your log/(development/test/production).log when you do a `group.blog.blog_posts.tag_counts` ?

Comment: SELECT tags.id, tags.name, COUNT(*) AS count FROM `tags` INNER JOIN taggings ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id INNER JOIN blog_posts ON blog_posts.id = taggings.taggable_id #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb164d53c> WHERE (#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb164e388> AND taggings.taggable_type = 'BlogPost') GROUP BY tags.id, tags.name HAVING COUNT(*) > 0

Comment: @user1865578 Please edit your first post with the new classes, the tests you've done (group.blog, group.blog.blog_posts and group.blog.blog_posts.tag_counts) and respectively their database queries. There is somethink wrong with your association between tag and blog_post.

Comment: No this is how the query was actually formed in the application so its obviously wrong. Are you suggesting that I manually modify the query and try to run it to see if it works? Also FYI I have added  acts_as_taggable_on_steroids as a plugin and the BlogPost is declared as acts_as_taggable